# Why am I losing my array values after the for loop?

Tags: java, image

I am facing the following problems:

- Array values are lost after looping through the `for`-loop
- I am unable to display the image using `createImage()`
- I am getting a `NullPointerException`

Here's my code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Component;

class JpegData{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            File imgfile=new File("E:/Problems/","Lee.jpg");
            Component comp = null;
            int[] array = new int[1000];
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgfile); // ImageIO is final so no need to instatiate it
            System.out.println("Height:" + img.getHeight());
            System.out.println("Width:" + img.getWidth());

            for (int height = 500; height < 550; height++) {
                for (int width = 660; width < 680; width++) {
                    int pixel = img.getWidth()*(height-1)+(width);
                    int a = 0;
                    array[a] = img.getRGB(width, height);   

                    Color clr = new Color(img.getRGB(width, height));
                    System.out.print("Pixel-" + pixel + ": "+"R:" + clr.getRed() + " G:" + clr.getGreen() + " B:" + clr.getBlue());
                    System.out.println("at pixel:" + pixel + "rgb:" + img.getRGB(width,height));
                    a++;
                }
            }

            for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) System.out.println(array[i]);
            Image dis = comp.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(20, 50, array, 0, 1)); 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error.Input Output Exception occured.");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error stacktrace?

Comment: You never initialize `comp`

Comment: you have not assigned anything to your `Component comp=null;` so how can you call `comp.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(20, 50, array, 0, 1));`? it is a NullPointerException!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at JpegData.main(JpegData.java:34)

Comment: Why shouldn't we initialize comp? @cricket_007

Comment: createImage(new MemoryImageSource(20, 50, array, 0, 1)); I tried calling this, got an error :cannot find symbol. Can you please explain me in detail of how to display those pixels and why is my array showing all 0's even though it has been assigned values

Comment: No, you **should**, but you haven't. Therefore it's null, and your error happens

Comment: Component comp=new Component(); cannot be used because it is an abstract class. Then how do I initialize comp @cricket_007